# How can I install Moonlight in Chrome in Linux?

Tags: chrome, moonlight

I am trying to just click on the appropriate link on [the Moonlight download page](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx), but after it downloads I get [a support warning](http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning). The text seems to be designed for Windows, because I couldn't get it to work.